# Web and Service layer Split up

Tags: angularjs, spring, architecture

I have a front-end written using angular, grunt, and bower. And I have a backend, which is mostly just a REST API (Spring application).

Building them separately as two different wars(web.war & service.war).I strictly need only static files inside web.war

My question is, to make front and back end communicate, where should I place the controller(inside web or service war).  Is it good to have controller at service side itself?  What is the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

I should suggest you to add controllers in web.war, IMHO, it makes no sense to add a controller class in a service.war, maybe you have a specific requirements, but I do not understand why you have a war for service module, I should merge two wars in only war.
regards

Comment: Service war is acting as an API (which serves many different UI).That's the reason for the separate service war. Here comes the doubt,where to have my controller.Whether to have individual controller for different UI's or a common controller in service war for all UI. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I should have one controller per UI. Do not mix different stuff.

Comment: Then different UI's should have their own controller?So at the end i should have my controller at web.war instead of service.war?